# Related to Integration

Tags: integration, problem-solving

I didn't crack the solution of this

$\int{\frac{e^{-λ/x}}{x}}dx$ $=I(say)$

I am using by parts and stuck at $2I=$$\int{\frac{e^{-λ/x}logx}{x}}dx$

I did not understand where do I go wrong? If not then how to proceed.

Comment: This function does't have an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: Please check this ode. $\frac{dy}{dx} +\frac{λ}{x^2}y=\frac{c}{x}$

Comment: and if you don't mind can you please tell me how you determined that the given function has no antiderivative?

Comment: Your integrating factor is correct. However, the integral has no elementary antiderivative because, through the change of variable $u = \lambda/x$, you can see that the solution ito it is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Comment: Actually this thing comes from this $\frac{d}{dx}(x\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{λ}{x}y)=0$ where $λ>0$  having the boundary condition $y(0)+y_1(0)=0$  and $y(1)+y_1(1)=0$ .Asking to find the eigen value and related eigen function

I try this but did not understand how to solve this?

Comment: Are you doing Sturm-Liouville problems? And what is $y_{1}$ supposed to represent? How is $y_{1}$ different from $y$?

Comment: here $y_1$ represents $\frac{dy}{dx}$ .
Actually I'm not sure  .In my book's exercise, there just ask to find the eigenvalue and eigenfunction.

Comment: Are you sure it is $$\frac{d}{dx} \left( x \frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{\lambda}{x} y \right) = 0$$ and not $$\frac{d}{dx} \left( x \frac{dy}{dx} \right) + \frac{\lambda}{x}y = 0$$ ? Also, which book are you looking at and what is the name of the chapter?

Comment: I do think the same and so I cross checked it. Maybe there is a printing mistake in my book. Ok, I will be searching this type in any other books. If you find something then please inform me here. God bless. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't mind, Can you explain this, 

please click the below link:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279248/explanation-related-to-a-rule-in-d-operator?noredirect=1#comment4693199_2279248